# Is "his bad" alright?

Tags: phrases

I've seen many people using 'my bad' for an apology, 
so is it alright to use 'his bad' or 'her bad' by the same token?

Comment: It’s a very informal approach to an apology- some might consider it rude. But “by the same token” yes, you can say, “Don’t worry, it was her bad not yours.”

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Since "my bad" is informal, so would be "his bad".  And bear in mind that it would be an accusation, not an apology.

Answer (score 0):

***[My bad](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/my-bad)*** is  an informal AmE expression:

> - used for saying that you accept that you are wrong or that something is your fault:
>
>   - *"You brought the wrong book." "Okay, my bad. I'll go get it."*

It is generally used in the first person by the speaker who admits a mistake and apologises for that mistake.

Referring to a third person you would, more respectfully, talk about a "fault  or a responsibility," though "his/her bad" would be understood.